# JavaScript prototypal inheritance to show parent object name

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I've been reading about JavaScript prototypal inheritance and the prototype property, and I started making a fiddle to understand the concepts better. But I need help understanding why my example isn't working as I thought it would.

In the following example, I'm trying to create a hierarchy where when you create an object, it tells you the name of the parent object. However, my logs always return "object".

One article explained that prototype chaining works so that if a property is not found on the object, the prototype of the parent is checked, and it keeps going up until 'Object', and if not found returns undefined.

Here's a fiddle to go along: http://jsfiddle.net/hqozqd0m/

```js
Object.prototype.cname = 'object';

function plant() {
    function parentname() { return this.cname; }
    return {
        parentname:parentname
    }
}
plant.prototype.cname = 'plant';

function tomato() { 
    function parentname() { return this.cname; }
    return {
        parentname:parentname
    }
}
tomato.prototype = new plant(); // <-- settings it to plant as parent

var p = new plant();
var t = new tomato();

console.log(p.parentname()); //object
console.log(t.parentname()); //object
```

---

updated code - same result

```
Object.prototype.cname = 'object';

function plant() {
    this.sayparentname = function() { console.log(cname); };
}
plant.prototype.cname = 'plant';

function tomato() { 
    this.sayparentname = function() { console.log(cname); };
}
tomato.prototype = new plant();

var p = new plant();
var t = new tomato();

p.sayparentname();
t.sayparentname();
```

Comment: You are incorrectly mixing two different styles. The one with new and the one where literal objects are returned from functions invoked without new.

Answer (score 2):

Normally a constructor function will modify the object that `new` creates, with statements such as `this.foo = bar`, and not return anything. Then the result of the `new` expression is the object.

However, if the function returns an object, that object will replace the one that `new` created; so when you use `new plant()` you're just getting a plain Object instance back.

To fix your code you just need to make it like this:

```
function Plant() {
    function parentName() { return this.cname; }

    this.parentName = parentName;
}
```

Comment: wait what - i just re-read that. so how do you create a new plant then?

Comment: see my updated code. I'm not returning anything from the constructors this time. same result

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: you are missing this in front of cname.